# xsd attribute minOccurs="0" is not working for type="xsd:dateTime"

Tags: datetime, xsd, wsdl

In my wsdl i want the date field to be optional for that in the wsdl i gave

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Date" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true" >
        </xsd:element>
```

but its is not working.it is expecting value in this field.How make a dateTime field optional?can anyone please help

Comment: `minOccurs="0"` will allow the entire `Date` element to be absent.  Is this what you want, or is it that you want `Date` to be able to be empty when present?

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the nillable attribute, keeping the minOccurs.

Comment: i tried with removing nillable now I see that the field is optional but i'm getting unmarshelling error in that line    <xsd:element  minOccurs="0" name="Date" type="xsd:dateTime"  >
        </xsd:element> it seems it is expecting some value in that field

Comment: Add a stack trace of your exception please to help you further. Are you generating any Jaxb objects? And is it your request xsd?